# How to POST form data from React Front End to my backend?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, rest, express

I'm trying to figure out how to send React Form data to my backend and into my mongoDB database. I can create an admin and log them in when testing this out in postman but I cannot figure out how to send the form data from React to my backend. I use Nodejs and Express on the backend.

This is my form

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import dotenv from "dotenv";
dotenv.config();

const baseUrl = process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL;


export const Register = () => {
  const [admin, setAdmin] = useState({
    username: '',
    email: '',
    password: ''
  })

  // define an admin
  const { username, email, password } = admin

  // use user input data to set the admin
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    setAdmin({
      ...admin,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    })
  }

  const registerAdmin = async (admin) => {
    const res = await fetch(`${baseUrl}/admins/register`, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(admin),
  })
  console.log(res)
}

  // once admin is set, pass that data when submitted
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        // call API function to send admin data to backend
        registerAdmin(admin)
        // after admin is sent to the backend, reset state
        setAdmin({
          username: '',
          email: '',
          password: ''
        })
      }


  return (
      <>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <section className="hero is-primary is-fullheight">
            <div className="hero-body">
              <div className="container">
                <div className="columns is-centered">
                  <div className="column is-5-tablet is-4-desktop is-3-widescreen">
                    <form action="" className="box">
                    <h1 className="has-text-centered">Register Form</h1>
                      <div className="field">
                        <label htmlFor="" className="label">Username</label>
                        <div className="control has-icons-left">
                          <input type="text" value={username} name="username" onChange={handleChange} placeholder="username" className="input" required />
                          <span className="icon is-small is-left">
                            <i className="fa fa-envelope"></i>
                          </span>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div className="field">
                        <label htmlFor="" className="label">Email</label>
                        <div className="control has-icons-left">
                          <input type="email" value={email} name="email" onChange={handleChange} placeholder="e.g. bobsmith@gmail.com" className="input" required />
                          <span className="icon is-small is-left">
                            <i className="fa fa-envelope"></i>
                          </span>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div className="field">
                        <label htmlFor="" className="label">Password</label>
                        <div className="control has-icons-left">
                          <input type="password" value={password} name="password"
                            onChange={handleChange} placeholder="*******" className="input" required />
                          <span className="icon is-small is-left">
                            <i className="fa fa-lock"></i>
                          </span>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div className="field">
                        <Link to='/' type="submit" className="button is-success">
                          Register
                </Link>
                      </div>
                    </form>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </section>
        </form>
      </>
    )
  }
```

This is the code in my server.

```
import express from 'express';
import session from 'express-session'
import connectMongo from 'connect-mongo';
import db from './db.js'

// allows us to take in incoming post request body
import bodyParser from 'body-parser'
import dotenv from 'dotenv';

// bring in the admins routes
import adminsRoutes from './routes/admins.js'

dotenv.config();

const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT;
const MongoStore = connectMongo(session);

let sessionOptions = session({
  secret: process.env.SECRET,
  store: new MongoStore({client: db}),
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  cookie: {maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24, httpOnly: true}
})

app.use(sessionOptions)

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// tell express to use the admins routes
// set the starting path for all the routes in the admins.js
app.use('/admins', adminsRoutes);

// route to the homepage
app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello from home page'));

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is listening on port: ${PORT}`)
})
```

Any pointers or tips in any of my code is greatly appreciated.
Thank you for your time!

Comment: you are stringify in react so you need to parse it in backend

Comment: You should post the code for this part: `app.use('/admins', adminsRoutes);`  so we can see where this goes: `fetch(`${baseUrl}/admins/register`